# How to get values from a Jobject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am using the Newtonsoft JSon c# plugin. I jave a JArray

```
{"data":[{"name":"Wesley 1","id":"616611941"},{"name":"Wesley 2","id":"100000138033375"},..............
```

I was wondering is there a way to loop though each object between the curly braces and extract the name and id of each entry?

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: I guess the client is javascript, isn't it?

Comment: I need to loop through it using c#.

Comment: I guess you can find it easily in docs :) http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jQuery you can do this. First loop will go thorough each item in array. second loop will get the key, value in each array item

```
$.each(data, function() {
  $.each(this, function(key, value) {
    //do what ever you want
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

OK. You got some good answers from others. Here is another way.

namespace

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

You add strongly typed class that maps data in the json

```
public class wordList
{
    public List<NameId> data { get; set; }
    public wordList() 
    { 
        data = new List<NameId>(); 
    }
}

public class NameId
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }        
}
```

then you call

```
 string jsonObj = @"{""data"":[{""name"":""Wesley 1"",""id"":""616611941""},{""name"":""Wesley 2"",""id"":""100000138033375""}]}";

 JavaScriptSerializer jsSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 wordList wl = jsSer.Deserialize<wordList>(jsonObj);
```

You can loop through the WordList to get the name, id values

Comment: OK mate. I see your question is already answered. Anyway I have edited my post with another option.

Comment: Thanks yours is the best out of the lot. I done something like this myself to get it working without creating classes. I used the js serializer but combined it with a dynamic c# dictionary. Worked lovely.

Answer (score 2):

According to some other questions you could try:

```
var array = JArray.Parse(json);
```

and then do a

```
foreach(var item in array)
    // do something
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in dynObj.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",item.name,item.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; 
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<JObject> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(requestBody); 
   foreach(JObject d in data)
                    {
                        
                        string name = d.GetValue("name").ToString();
                        string id = d.GetValue("id").ToString();
                     
                    }
```